# Accessing Spring bean in custom Log4j2 appender

Tags: java, spring, log4j2

Q1: I would like to process log events in my Spring bean. Is there any way how to inject Spring bean into Log4j2 AbstractAppender?

I have such testing appender implementation:

```
@Plugin(name = "Basic", category = "Core", elementType = "appender", printObject = true)
public class BasicAppender extends AbstractAppender {

  private static volatile BasicAppender instance;

  private ConcurrentMap<String, LogEvent> eventMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  public BasicAppender(String name, Filter filter, Layout<? extends Serializable> layout, boolean ignoreExceptions, Property[] properties) {
    super(name, filter, layout, ignoreExceptions, properties);
  }

  @PluginFactory
  public static BasicAppender createAppender(
      @PluginAttribute("name") String name,
      @PluginAttribute("ignoreExceptions") boolean ignoreExceptions,
      @PluginElement("Layout") Layout layout,
      @PluginElement("Filters") Filter filter
  ) {

    if (layout == null) {
      layout = PatternLayout.createDefaultLayout();
    }

    instance = new BasicAppender(name, filter, layout, false, null);

    return instance;

  }

  public static BasicAppender getInstance() {
    return instance;
  }

  @Override
  public void append(final LogEvent event) {
    eventMap.put(Instant.now().toString(), event);
  }

}
```

Q2: And second question, I would like to make this appender async. Is this possible?